# How to configure installed Ruby and gems?

Tags: linux, ruby, rubygems

My current `gem env` returns:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/USERNAME/.gems
  - RUBYGEMS PREFIX: /home/narkoz
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/USERNAME/.gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/USERNAME/.gems
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gempath" => ["/home/USERNAME/.gems", "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"]
     - "gemhome" => "/home/USERNAME/.gems"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

How can I change path `/home/USERNAME/` to my own without uninstalling?
OS: Debian Linux

Comment: Good question +1. I mean, basically anything about ruby gems is a good question, I think :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `.gemrc` file in your home path. Put these lines:

```
gemhome: /home/CHANGE_IT_TO_USERNAME/.gems
gempath:
  - /home/CHANGE_IT_TO_USERNAME/.gems
```

[Documentation about gem configuration file](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/11)

Comment: https://guides.rubygems.org/faqs/#user-install

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry if I've misunderstood the question but can you not just do:

```
export GEM_PATH=/home/myown
```

Maybe put it in your .bashrc.